# C# Parse.com - Setting and deleting Push Notification Channels

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

In my WP8 Application I am trying to setup my channels for push notifications using Parse.com when a user logs in. For now I am just using a static channel reference to try and get this working. However my problem is that each time I call Installation.saveAsync() this creates a new installation rather than updating the installation for the device. Looking in the Data Browser I think that the problem is that the installisation seems to have no deviceToken.

I don't really know what I am doing wrong as the code I am using is coming directly from the Parse documentation. I have attached my code for initialising parse below to see if anyone can spot my error

```
internal async static void Initialise()
{
    ParseClient.Initialize(appId, donNetKey);
    ParseFacebookUtils.Initialize(facebookId);

    var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
    installation.Channels = new List<string>() { "example" };
    await installation.SaveAsync();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using an actual device or an emulator?

Comment: A actual device. The device is WP8.1, but as Parse.com doesn't support 8.1 yet, my app is still WP8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that I was uninstalling the app at certain points and when I was reinstalling the app again, parse doesn't detect that it already has an installation for the device, so it creates another.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your problem or not, but try resetting the badge.
installation["badge"] = 0;

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update this post. The issue ended up being that I was uninstalling the app at certain points and when I was reinstalling the app again, parse doesn't detect that it already has an installation for the device, so it creates another.